# Generating Incomparable Unit Sums of Complex Numbers

Tags: probability-theory, complex-numbers

Call two complex numbers $a, b$ `incomparable' if either $Re(a) > Re(b)$ and $Im(b) > Im(a)$, or $Re(b) > Re(a)$ and $Im(a) > Im(b)$ (where $Re(x)$ and $Im(x)$ denote $x$'s real and imaginary components, respectively). In words, two complex numbers are incomparable if one has a greater real component and the other has a greater imaginary component.

(How) Can one define a function that returns, for any positive integer $n > 0$ a set $\textbf{C} = \{c_{1}, ..., c_{n}\}$ of $n$ distinct complex numbers such that

(i) $\sum \limits_{c \in \textbf{C}} c = 1$

(ii) For any non-empty disjoint subsets $Y, Y'$ of $\textbf{C}$, $\sum \limits_{c \in Y} c$ is incomparable to $\sum \limits_{c' \in Y'} c'$.

Comment: As defined, your relation of incomparability is [antisymmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisymmetric_relation). If $\ a,b\ $ are incomparable, then $\ Re(a)>Re(b)\ $, so $\ Re(b)\not>Re(a)\ $, and $\ b,a\ $ *cannot* be incomparable. Are you sure that's what you want?  If it is, then the answer to your question is "no"—the sets $\ \mathbf{C}\ $ which the function whose definition you've asked for are suppoed to return cannot possibly exist.

Comment: Thanks for this -- it was of course a mistake -- edited now.